# Wix pre-installation requirments

Tags: wix, wix3.7

I am writing an installer to my application using wix3.8.

Before installing I need to check some machine requirements, and if the current machine does not have those requirements don't install my application.

The requirements are:
1. OS- win 8.1 and up.
2. CPU- HSW GT2 and up.

How do I add a check for these requirements in wix?
Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you will need to write a customaction to check for CPU but for OS you can do a check like this

```
<Condition Message="This application is only supported on Windows 8.1, or higher.">
    <![CDATA[Installed OR (VersionNT >= 603)]]>
</Condition>
```

Reference: [How To: Block Installation Based on OS Version](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/redistributables_and_install_checks/block_install_on_os.html)

To develop a custom action you can refer to the following articles. Basically you need to create function that does all the checks you want and expose it in your custom action library. Then you can call this function from your installer script.

Reference:

- [Adding Custom Actions](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixdev/extensions/authoring_custom_actions.html)
- [Custom actions in C#](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jschaffe/archive/2012/10/23/creating-wix-custom-actions-in-c-and-passing-parameters.aspx)

Comment: VersionNT value for windows 8.1 is 603. 600 is for windows vista and server 2008.

Comment: Thanks! can you refer me to an explanation how do I write a costumaction?

Comment: added a few references to the above post.

Comment: Thanks, will look into that. Does it matter where to write the condition?

Comment: They are called in sequence so choose appropriately

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in Windows Installer **LaunchCondition feature**:

- http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/redistributables_and_install_checks/block_install_on_os.html

The statements are written in **Conditional Statement Syntax**:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368012(v=vs.85).aspx

Here are the **Operating System Property Values**:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370556(v=vs.85).aspx

Here are some samples (not tested):

- Vista: NOT VersionNT OR (VersionNT >= 600)
- Windows 8.1:  VersionNT=603 WindowsBuild=9600

---

I think you can use the LaunchCondition feature for the CPU as well, check the Hardware properties:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370905(v=vs.85).aspx#hardware_properties

Comment: Thanks. The Launch condition feature is working as expected. As for the CPU- the HW property does not help me.